Mysql Select distinct by one column but return distinct of another column that corresponds to that row
I have this query
SELECT id, card_id FROM sp_answered 
This will return distinct but using the 2 columns.
What I need is SELECT card_id FROM sp_answered but, I need to return only the id that corresponds to each distinct card_id.
This way, I can feed it into other queries.
I've tried group by but they need aggregate functions and combining it with having doesn't help either.
Example
table: sp_answered
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|    id | card_id   | answer    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|    1  |    110     | Answer 1  |
|    2  |    111     | Anwer 2   |
|    3  |    112     | Anwer 3   |
|    4  |    111     | Anwer 4   |
|    5  |    114     | Anwer 5   |
|    6  |    115     | Anwer 6   |
|    7  |    111     | Anwer 7   |
|    8  |    117     | Anwer 8   |
|    9  |    111     | Anwer 9   |
|   10  |    111     | Anwer 10  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+

You can see that there are duplicate card_ids' with card_id of  (111).
The result looks like below when I filter by card_id,
SELECT DISTINCT card_id FROM sp_answered 
table: sp_answered
+------------+
| card_id    |
+------------+
|    110     |
|    111     |
|    112     |
|    114     |
|    115     |
|    117     |
+------------+

However, I want to filter by card_id but get back the id instead.
Expected result.
table: sp_answered
+------------+
| card_id    |
+------------+
|    1       |
|    2       |
|    3       |
|    5       |
|    6       |
|    8       |
+------------+


By which logic should the id value be returned when you have mulitple entries for the same card_id value? For the card_id 111, there are the possible values 2, 4, 7, 9 and 10. Why is it 2 in your case and not say... 7? Add this information to your question.

https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=0052b1cf-8b91-4ca4-b2b2-f4fe0aff6df5
SELECT min(id), card_id 
FROM sp_answered
GROUP BY card_id;

or just
SELECT min(id)
FROM sp_answered
GROUP BY card_id;


What If I have this SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM task GROUP BY user_id but what I want is the id and the id is uuid  column?

It is not clear what you are asking for. Just create your own question with some sample of data structure, data sample and your question. And you can mention me in the comment there
